# Bootstrap-Table Jquery como editar individualmente uma coluna no evento de carregar tabela?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, jquery-datatables, table

Bootstrap-Table Jquery como editar individualmente uma coluna no evento de carregar tabela?

Já tentei sem sucesso usando nos eventos all.bs.table and data-load-success..

```
for(i=0;i < data.length; i++) {
    total_media = parseFloat(total_media)  +  parseFloat(data[i].lucro);
    data[i].lucro = ' test ' + String(data[i].lucro);
    jQuery("#tabela").bootstrapTable('updateRow', {index: i, row:  data[i] });
```

tentei assim tambem :

```
jQuery(data).each(function(i){
    total_media = total_media + parseFloat(data[i].lucro);
    data[i].lucro = 'test ' + String(data[i].lucro);    
    jQuery("#tabela").bootstrapTable('updateRow', {index: i, row:  data[i] });
```

e assim :

```
var total_media = data.reduce(function(a, b){
    lucro = b.lucro;
    b.lucro = ' test ' + String(b.lucro);
    jQuery("#tabela").bootstrapTable('updateRow', {index: a, row:  b });
    return a + parseFloat(lucro);
}, 0);
```

---

Bootstrap-Table Jquery como editar individualmente uma coluna no evento de carregar tabela?

Já tentei sem sucesso usando nos eventos all.bs.table and data-load-success..
Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Você que colocar edições no conteúdo de uma coluna especifica ?

Comment: sim, no evento de refresh da tabela.. apartir dos  dado recebidos do evento.

Comment: Beleza, vou responder

Answer (score 0):

Simples Rafael.

Primeiro você vai fazer uma função, que estiliza a coluna, que irá ser executada independente se houve um `update`, `insert` etc, então vamos lá, vou dar um exemplo. Imagine que existe uma tabela que lista projetos web, e uma das informações (colunas) desses projetos são os planos, e dependendo do plano, ele terá uma estilização diferente.

Primeiro, vamos dizer a está coluna, que ela terá uma função para executar, que será executada quando os dados forem recebidos, para isso utilizamos `data-formatter=""` do `Bootstrap Table.`

> OBS: O valor do `attr` `data-formatter` será o nome da função.

Bom, após criarmos a referencia no `html`, vamos para o `Js`. vamos criar uma função que recebe `value, row e index`, destá forma: `function myCustomPlans(value, row, index)`

> OBS: As funções para formatação das colunas devem ficar fora da
>   function `$(document).ready(function(){);`

Bom, agora é só fazermos a lógica de estilização dos planos. Algo do tipo:

```
function myCustomPlans(value, row, index) {
  var content;
  if (value == "eco") {
    content = "<span style='color: #4caf50'>" + value + "</span>";
  } else if (value == "premium") {
    content = "<span style='color: #fbc02d'>" + value + "</span>";
  } else {
    content = "<span style='color: #03a9f4'>" + value + "</span>";
  }
  return content;
}
```

De acordo com o valor que a coluna vai receber, será imprimido com uma cor diferente em um `span`.

Com está função que estiliza todas as células de uma determinada coluna pronta, podemos realizar vários `inserts` e `updates` normalmente, porque após ser executado estás ações, na hora de imprimir o conteúdo, a função do `data-formatter` será executada.

Espero ter ajudado.